# Exit journey on a specific date?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm creating a Journey to drive registration for an event.  Contacts should exit the journey either by registering (that's the Goal) or else on the start date of the event -- not some number of days after the previous activity.

Journey Builder won't let me replace the final Wait by Duration activity with a Wait Until Date, which would seem to be the obvious solution.  Nor can I have a Wait Until Date followed by a Wait by Duration.

I could potentially set the Wait by Duration based on the send date of the various reminder emails, but this would be clumsy and error-prone since there are numerous emails across different paths.

What's the best way to set something like this up?

Comment: Is the start date of the event same for all contacts entering the journey?  If so, just stop the journey on that day, everyone will exit the journey on the event start date :D 

If the event start is different for each contact, populate the event start date in the journey DE (at the start of journey) and use that to exit the contacts in decision split wise.

Comment: The start is the same for everyone.  Didn't see a place to specify the Journey end date...only start date.  Entry source is Data Extension, with no repeats.  The real question is how to keep people in the journey right up until the start of the event, giving them the maximum possible time to attain the goal.

Comment: why u want the contact to be in journey even after sending the last communication (email)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it when you insert a different activity like email send into the journey at the end. Then you place the wait until date before the email send (and a wait by duration will automatically be inserted after the email send). Then you delete the email activity and you got what you wanted. Wait until date followed by wait by duration.

Very unintuitive;)

Comment: I tried this, but the resulting Journey won't validate.  Error message is: "The journey has two or more consecutive wait activities. Remove a wait activity or add an activity between them."

Answer (score 0):

There are a few of ways to do it.

1) Before the last communication (email) activity, choose "Wait Until Date" activity. So, the last touch point would be on that Date.  After Email activity, add a wait by duration and put say 1 minute (that exits immediately).

2) Have a date field say Opt-Out date in DE.  Then set the exit criteria of the journey Opt-out date is equal to a specified date (your event start date say Jan 17 in the example below).

[image]

3) Just don't put any goal or exit criteria, so the contacts stay in the journey longer (as you wanted) and finally on the event day, turn off journey so all contacts exit on that day.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but found this workaround that might be useful for others in the future:

1. Create your "Wait Until Date" activity, place where you want
2. DRAG the final "1 day" wait activity to another place in the journey
3. Save and exit the journey
4. Return to the journey - you can now delete your extraneous wait activity